# How to get event between Ajax.BeginForm and OnSuccess?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, ajaxform

I have a form, which I submit using `Ajax.BeginForm`. I want to do the following:

1. Submitting the form with all the data (using `Ajax.BeginForm`)
2. While we're waiting for the controller, do some work - including truncating my textarea
3. When the controller is done (using `OnSuccess`), do some more stuff

However, while 1) and 3) works perfectly, I don't know which way to access #2. I have tried using the JavaScript event `submit` on the form, but it seems this event happens before, so if I empty my textarea the controller never sees this filled value.

**My Razor:**

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateNotification", "Task",null, new AjaxOptions() {HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess= "newMessage" },new {id="conv_form"}))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.ConversationId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.New_Message, new {@class = "form-control conversation-box"})
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Send message" id="conversation_message_submit" class="btn btn-link pull-right" style="color: black; padding-right: 0px; font-size: 12pt;"/>

    }
```

**I also have my jQuery:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /// Here I plan to truncate my textarea + other stuff
        $('#conv_form').submit(function () {
            console.log('conv_form submit');
        });
    });

    function newMessage(data) {
        console.log('newmessage fired');

    }
</script>
```

So my challenge is that with my `submit` event, if I manipulate the fields this will change what we send to the controller. I want to access an event which is between what is sent to controller and the `OnSuccess`.

Comment: have you tried using jQuery's ajaxStart() function https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

Comment: Use the [AjaxOptions.OnBegin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onbegin(v=vs.118).aspx) property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try ajaxStart

```
 $('#conv_form').submit(function () {
        console.log('conv_form submit');
    });
}).ajaxStart(function(){
      //DoYourStuff
    })
    .ajaxStop(function(){
        //Stop Your Stuff
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ajaxStart` for do step 2 like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
   // do step 2
});
```

The `ajaxStart()` method specifies a function to be run when an AJAX request starts. As of `jQuery version 1.9`, this method should only be attached to `document`. For more information please see [this](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/).